# Reading XML on WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xml-parsing

I was wondering how to read this xml with Windows Phone (The document tree is shown below):

```
<reponse>Please verify your email </reponse>
```

I want to display a MessageBox containing : "Please verify your email".

Answer (score 0):

I think this link will give you an good overview of how to do this. http://windowsphone.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/android-to-wp7-chapter-7-xml-parsing-in-windows-phone-7-and-android (It describes a few possibilities)

I personally would use Linq to XML.

And another link to an article about using Linq to XML http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/wp7-working-with-xml-reading-filtering-and-databinding

This code should work:

```
var xmlResult = XDocument.Parse("<reponse>Please verify your email </reponse>");
var responseValue = xmlResult.Element("response").Value;
```